# SQL Excel VBA Run-time Error 3709 Invalid Connection

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first question so constructive criticism is welcome! I am attempting to query an access database from excel vba and place the return information into an Excel range. I get this error:

> Error Message: "Run-time error '3709' The connection cannot be used to
>   perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this
>   context."

Code:

```
Sub Importfromaccess()
        Path = "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Database1.accdb"

        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")

        cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Path & ";"

        Set rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

        rs1.activeconnection = cn

        Dim strSQL As New ADODB.Command

        strSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tooling WHERE TID=BD0001"
        strSQL.CommandType = adCmdText

        Set rs1 = strSQL.Execute ' This is the line the error occurs on

        Sheets("Calc").Range("K1").CopyFromRecordset rs1
End Sub
```

I have enabled the following references:

1. Visual Basic For Applications,
2. Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library,
3. OLE Automation,
4. Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library,
5. Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library,
6. Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library,

I tried placing the line:

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Path & ";"
```

right before the error line and received this error:

> Run-time error '3705': Operation is not allowed when the object is
>   open.

Anybody know what my problem might be?

Comment: Thank you all so much for the answers! That was so fast!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First (and unrelated to your error), unless you need to support clients using Windows 2000 or earlier, you should reference the highest Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects version instead of 2.0.  If you're only using ADODB to interact with the database, you don't need the Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library at all.

Second, if you ***already have a reference***, don't create late bound objects like this:

> ```
> Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
> ```

Adding the reference early binds the type, so explicitly declare them and instantiate them using `New`:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
```

Your connection string should be fine - where you run into problems are these 2 lines:

> ```
>     Set rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
>
>     rs1.activeconnection = cn
> ```

Executing an `ADODB.Command` will return the `Recordset`, not the other way around.  Remove those 2 lines entirely.  Instead of attaching the connection to the `Recordset`, you need to use it when you're building your `ADODB.Command`:

```
    Dim strSQL As New ADODB.Command
    strSQL.ActiveConnection = cn      '<---Insert this.
    strSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
    strSQL.CommandType = adCmdText
```

Also, get rid of the Hungarian notation there - it's confusing as hell.  An ADODB command isn't a `String`, so why should it be named `strFoo`?

You also need to clean up after yourself - don't leave your recordset and connection just hanging open when you're done with them.  Call `.Close` when you're finished.

Finally, your SQL statement is most likely incorrect - you probably need to enclose your `TID` in single quotes(`'`):

```
"SELECT * FROM Tooling WHERE TID='BD0001'"
```

It should look closer to this:

```
Sub Importfromaccess()
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Database1.accdb"

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Path & ";"

    Dim query As New ADODB.Command
    query.ActiveConnection = cn
    query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tooling WHERE TID='BD0001'"
    query.CommandType = adCmdText

    Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs1 = query.Execute ' This is the line the error occurs on

    Sheets("Calc").Range("K1").CopyFromRecordset rs1

    'CLEAN UP AFTER YOURSELF:
    rs1.Close
    cn.Close 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man. I learned a lot just form reading through that. I had no idea my code was so riddled with errors O.o

Answer (score 1):

You already `Set rs1`

How about trying something more like:

```
Sub Importfromaccess()
  Dim strSQL As String, strPath as String
  Dim cn as Object, rs1 as Object

  strPath = "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Database1.accdb"
  Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")

  cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Path & ";"

  Set rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Tooling WHERE TID='BD0001'"
  rs1.Open strSQL, cn

  Sheets("Calc").Range("K1").CopyFromRecordset rs1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After some thorough rearranging I think I figured it out. I'm surprised at what changes fixed the problem but the following code works:

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tooling WHERE TID='BD0001'"
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Database1.accdb;"

cmd.ActiveConnection = con

Set rs = cmd.Execute

Sheets("Calc").Range("K1").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
con.Close
```

The final error was fixed with:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tooling WHERE TID='BD0001'"
```

this line previously did not include single quotes around BD0001.

I also added an ActiveConnection to the Command object.

Edit: This is the simplest working version of this I could manage courtesy of all you helpful people!

Comment: You should add a rs.Close and a cn.Close at the end of your subroutine.

Comment: Error was due to the fact that you were opening connection before initializing recordset.

Comment: You need to remove the `New` from `Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset`.  This does the same thing your original code did - it creates a disconnected recordset that you *replace without* ***closing*** when you call `Set rs = cmd.Execute`. Correctness should ***always*** be preferred over brevity.

Comment: *fixed*. I didn't even notice that, thank you pointing it out!