# VBA connect with ADO to SQL Server (Windows authenticated)

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-authentication, ado

I get a runtime error 3709 when trying to connect via VBA to a SQL Server using Windows authentication.

The problem occurs on this line:

```
.ActiveConnection = conn
```

Here is the complete code used to connect:

```
Dim strConn As String
Dim wsReport As Worksheet
Dim col As Integer

strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "Server=" & Server_Name & ";"
strConn = strConn & "Database=" & Database_Name & ";"
strConn = strConn & "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
strConn = strConn & "Integrated Security=True;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

With conn
    .ConnectionString = strConn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
End With

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

With rst

    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .Open Source:=SQL_Statement
End With

Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

With wsReport
    For col = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
        .Cells(1, col + 1) = rst.Fields(col).Name
    
    Next col
End With
```

Or is ADO out of date now?

Comment: what is the error description?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304529/sql-excel-vba-run-time-error-3709-invalid-connection

Comment: Try removing "Trusted_Connection=yes". "Integrated Security=True" alone will provide Windows authentication. ADO is a "mature" technology that hasn't been improved in over 15 years but not officially deprecated. The SQLOLEDB driver that ships with Windows is deprecated, though, so you should move to use [MSOLEDBSQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56730) instead, a separate download and install.

Comment: THe Error message is: "Error Message: "Run-time error '3709' The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context."

Comment: I tried changing the provider to MSOLEDBSQL, and removing the "Trusted_Connection=yes" I still have the same problem. I also tried changing the code using "cn.Open strConn", like in the link. I then got a different runtime error "Run-time error '-21472127887 (80040e21)' "

Comment: after looking at this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1ljz9uVW4c I decided to connect via the excel connection wizard to sql-server, which worked great, but unlike the video, I couldn't see the conncetion string, which I would have done used  in my code. One odd thing I noticed, is that the provider was "Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1", but using this in the code  did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=XX;Database=XXXX;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

THis website gives all the different combinations according to the exact case, showing the complexities of connections with SQL-Server:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/